# map is not a function in react-native

Tags: react-native

I want to get some data from api and display data in my app. This is my code,
    class AlbumList extends Component {

```
state = { albums: [] };

async componentWillMount() {
try {
  const data = await axios.get(
      'https://rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/music_albums'
  );
  this.setState({ albums: data });
} catch (err) {
  console.error(err.message);
}
}

renderAlbums() {
  return this.state.albums.map(album => <Text>{album.title}</Text>);
}

render() {
return (
  <View>
    {this.renderAlbums()}
  </View>
 );
 }
 }
```

this will give a error this.state.albums.map is not a function..
any way to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error  "map it not a function" occurs because axios don't return an array.
Axios returns an object with keys like status, data.

```
const data = await axios.get(
  'https://rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/music_albums'
);
console.log(data);
console.log(data.data); // album data
this.setState({album: data.data});
```

When using without await:

```
axios.get('https://rallycoding.herokuapp.com/api/music_albums')
  .then(response => {
    this.setState({ album: response.data });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

So you must check the object key "data" returned by axios get.